# Head or Tails Probability order?

Tags: probability, statistics

> $10$ fair coins are flipped. What is the probability that at exactly $2$ of them are heads in any order.

What I am confused about is what formula does one use in order to solve this?

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n\\
        r \\
       \end{pmatrix} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
$$

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        10\\
        2 \\
       \end{pmatrix} = \frac{10!}{2!(10-2)!} = 45 $$

yet the answer is $.0439$. Any advise you guys on how to solve this?

Comment: there are 45 ways to flip 2 heads on 10 coins.  There are 1024 ways to flip 10 coins.

Comment: Where does the number 1024 come from?

Comment: Each coin flip can land on heads or tails. There are 2 possibilities for the first coin, 2 for the second, etc. So the total number of combinations is $2^{10}$ = 1024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $2^{10}=1024$ options overall, because each coin 'chooses' one side to fall on. All coins 'choose' a side independently. Finally, $$\frac{45}{{2^{10}}}=0.0439$$ - exactly what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways in which 2 heads may occur in a string of $10$ outcomes. Each string of $10$ outcomes has probability $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$. Hence the probability is $$\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{2^{10}} = \frac{45}{1024} = 0.0439$$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that there are $45$ ways to have exactly $2$ heads in $10$ flips. There are $1024$ combinations, however. So the probability of getting exactly $2$ heads is $\frac{45}{1024} = 0.0439.$